# Getting SQL Latest Rows based on Summary

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, rows, summary

I am having a table ItemTran in sql 2005 with the following columns

```
RowNo   Item ID     Period      RcptQty
1       ITEM-A      2011-01     15
2       ITEM-A      2011-02     10
3       ITEM-A      2011-03     18
4       ITEM-A      2011-04     25
5       ITEM-A      2011-05     3
6       ITEM-A      2011-06     12
7       ITEM-A      2011-07     15
8       ITEM-A      2011-08     5
9       ITEM-A      2011-09     15
10      ITEM-A      2011-10     8
11      ITEM-A      2011-11     10
12      ITEM-A      2011-12     5
```

There is a another table ItemQty with columns

```
Item ID     Qty
ITEM-A      78
```

How can i return the last rows from table ItemTran matching with RcptQty with the Table Column "Qty" from ItemQty Table.

i want the output like this

```
4   ITEM-A      2011-04     25
5   ITEM-A      2011-05     3
6   ITEM-A      2011-06     12
7   ITEM-A      2011-07     15
8   ITEM-A      2011-08     5
9   ITEM-A      2011-09     15
10  ITEM-A      2011-10     8
11  ITEM-A      2011-11     10
12  ITEM-A      2011-12     5
```

i want to fetch the last rows from ItemTran where the itemQty.Qty matches.

basically i want to get the last rows from Table A with summary matching with Table B.

Please help me on this. i am very new to sql.

Thanks

Comment: It's not clear how your filtering work, please re-read your question and add missing information so that we can help you

Comment: Need more info it makes no sense

Comment: Your expected output's `SUM(RcptQty)` is `98`. If we remove the `RowNo=4` row, we get `73`. Does that mean that the rows should be retrieved until `SUM(ItemTran.RcptQty)` exactly matches *or exceeds* the corresponding `ItemQty.Qty` value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume you meant "68" in ItemQty and that you are adding up the quantity for each month until you hit that magic number. Then you are looking for what month that target quantity was hit. I don't have sql server running, but the sql should be fairly close.

This statement assumes you really mean the totals match:

```
SELECT x.RowNo, x.Period, x.ItemID
  FROM ( SELECT RowNo, Period, ItemID
               ,SUM(RcptQty) OVER(PARTITION BY ItemId ORDER BY ItemId, period) AS running_total
           FROM ItemTran t
       ) x
      ,ItemQty q
  WHERE q.Qty = x.running_total
    AND q.ItemID = x.ItemID
```

This statement returns the last month before the threshold was hit:

```
 SELECT x.ItemID, MAX(x.Period)
  FROM ( SELECT RowNo, Period, ItemID
               ,SUM(RcptQty) OVER(PARTITION BY ItemId ORDER BY ItemId, period) AS running_total
           FROM ItemTran t
       ) x
      ,ItemQty q
  WHERE q.Qty <= x.running_total
    AND q.ItemID = x.ItemID
  GROUP BY x.ItemID
```

If someone else wants to play with this, here are the creation scripts I used:

```
CREATE TABLE ItemTran(RowNo int, ItemID varchar(16), Period date, RcptQty int);

INSERT INTO ItemTran VALUES(1, 'ITEM-A', '2011-01-01', 15);
INSERT INTO ItemTran VALUES(2, 'ITEM-A', '2011-02-01', 10);
INSERT INTO ItemTran VALUES(3, 'ITEM-A', '2011-03-01', 18);
INSERT INTO ItemTran VALUES(4, 'ITEM-A', '2011-04-01', 25);
INSERT INTO ItemTran VALUES(5, 'ITEM-A', '2011-05-01', 3);
INSERT INTO ItemTran VALUES(6, 'ITEM-A', '2011-06-01', 12);
INSERT INTO ItemTran VALUES(7, 'ITEM-A', '2011-07-01', 15);
INSERT INTO ItemTran VALUES(8, 'ITEM-A', '2011-08-01', 5);
INSERT INTO ItemTran VALUES(9, 'ITEM-A', '2011-09-01', 15);
INSERT INTO ItemTran VALUES(10, 'ITEM-A', '2011-10-01', 8);
INSERT INTO ItemTran VALUES(11, 'ITEM-A', '2011-11-01', 10);
INSERT INTO ItemTran VALUES(12, 'ITEM-A', '2011-12-01', 5);

CREATE TABLE ItemQty(ItemID varchar(16), Qty int);

INSERT INTO ItemQty VALUES('ITEM-A', 68);
```

Comment: I'm curious as to why you have assumed `68`, for I've assumed they meant `98` instead. :)

Comment: Also, `ORDER BY` is not supported in windowed aggregate functions until, probably, the coming version of SQL Server.

Comment: @AndriyM Yeah, the question really isn't clear, but it did seem like an interesting challenge... I guessed 68 since the first 4 records added up to 68 and I could imagine the problem as "These are our monthly sales, at what point did we hit our sales target of 68: month 4". I ran this with Postgres. I happened to be playing with analytic functions at the time so my mind was bent that way. But re-reading the question, I'm really not sure what is being asked.

Comment: Nor am I. My assumption is, the ItemTran's last rows' `SUM(RcptQty)` value should exactly match or just exceed that of `ItemQty.Qty`, but that is yet to be confirmed by the OP. Until then, my assumption is no better than yours.